# Using Keytool to export and change password of certificate in a KeyStore

Tags: certificates

I'd like to use Keytool to export a certificate from my KeyStore.

I'd also like to change the certificate password, is it possible?

What I thought should be done is one of the following:
1. Changing the certificate password during export
2. Changing the certificate password after export

I couldn't find a way to do either option with keytool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Changing the keystore password:

```
keytool -storepasswd -new new_storepass -keystore keystore.jks
```

2- Exporting the certificate:

```
keytool -export -alias mydomain -file mydomain.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```

[keytool](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html)

Comment: I don't want to change the existing keystore password.

Comment: The password is set to protect the private key. What exactly are you trying to do? Combine export cert and change pwd in the same command?

Comment: If you just want to export the certificate, you don't need to protect it with a pwd, it's not confidential (publicKey).

Answer (score 1):

My solution for changing the password on a certificate within a keystore was:

```
keytool -keypasswd -new NewCertPass -keystore keystore.jks -storepass KeystorePass -alias mydomain -keypass OldCertPass
```

Comment: Welcome. Can you explain why this works? We tend to like to see more than just a commandline optionset but some comments on why or how it answers the question.

Comment: Thanks Endareth, this command helped me. I didn't need to change the password, just verify that the one I have is correct.